# Trick to use windows drives like linux?

Tags: linux, file-browser

I hope to use 2 drives as just a combined one like linux. I mean I hope to use a special browser to show up the directories in a general way. For example,

I have a dir hierarchy like below.

> ```
> c:/myProject/dev/asset  
>                 /seqs  
> d:/myProject/lib/asset  
>                 /seqs
> ```

I hope to access in my special file browser like

> ```
> d:/myProject/dev/asset
> ```

Is there any trick to like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could `mount` or map the drive so it appears on your file system at a specific directory location. This makes the Windows drive letter layout appear more like a unified tree like Unix/POSIX.  Google for references but here's one to start:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/98195/how-to-mount-a-hard-drive-as-a-folder-on-your-windows-pc/